# Use symbols from an ELF file while linking an executable

Tags: c, gcc, linker, osdev

I am working on an operating system, and the problem I am stuck on right now has to do with linking kernel modules.

The Operating system has some kernel mode libc functions like `malloc`, `printf` etc. I can use those functions from my core kernel, but I would also like to be able to call them from the kernel modules.

The kernel modules are compiled and linked separately and put in the initrd and are then loaded by the kernel and their main function is called, and they can in turn call the kernel functions mentioned above, or at least that is what I want.

The problem is when I am linking the kernel modules, the linker has no knowledge about the location of `printf`, `malloc` or any other kernel function when linking a kernel module.

My setup is made in such a way that I have a `kernel.elf` which contains the code and data of the kernel and all symbols stripped, and a `kernel.sym` file which has all its section sizes set to zero except the symbol table section. Initally the linker outputs `kernel.elf` with code, data and symbol names, then I use `objcopy --extract-symbols` to remove symbols from `kernel.elf` and put them in `kernel.sym`.

My question is: Is there anyway I can tell the linker to lookup the values of the symbols it doesn't know from `kernel.sym`, so that when a module contains a call to `printf` for example, it would know the address it should call.

I have tried putting `kernel.sym` as a library using `-l:kernel.sym`, but the linker complained `cannot use executable 'build/kernel.sym' as input to a link`.

As a note, I am using `gcc` and `binutils` as my build toolchain, and targeting x86-64. All the kernel code and data are in a fixed location, the locations of functions like `printf` etc is known at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exploring a number of solutions, I would like to share some of them, the first one is what I ended up settling on. If anyone out there found themselves in this specific case you might want to explore the other solutions as well and learn a few things here and there.

## Solution I

I ended up writing a simple C program `modldgen` that reads the symbols in `kernel.sym` and outputs a linker script that contains core kernel symbols.

The source code for `modldgen` is as follows (commented):

```c
/*
  This tool generates a linker script that defines symbols from
  an ELF file.

  This is used in HeliumOS to link kernel modules with the ability
  to access core kernel symbols.
*/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <elf.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if(argc != 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <ELF-file> <ld-output-file>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *elf = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(!elf)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open ELF file '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *ld = fopen(argv[2], "w");
  if(!ld)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open linker script file '%s'.\n", argv[2]);
    return 2;
  }

  // Read symbol file header
  Elf64_Ehdr eh;
  fread(&eh, sizeof(eh), 1, elf);

  size_t sht_size = eh.e_shnum * eh.e_shentsize;
  fseek(elf, eh.e_shoff, SEEK_SET);

  uint8_t sht[sht_size];
  fread(sht, eh.e_shentsize, eh.e_shnum, elf);

  Elf64_Shdr *shstrtab_sh = (void *) sht + eh.e_shstrndx * eh.e_shentsize;

  // Load section header names from ELF file.
  uint8_t shstrtab[shstrtab_sh->sh_size];
  fseek(elf, shstrtab_sh->sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
  fread(shstrtab, 1, sizeof(shstrtab), elf);

  // Find string table
  Elf64_Shdr *strtab_sh = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < eh.e_shnum; ++i)
  {
    Elf64_Shdr *sh = (void *) sht + i * eh.e_shentsize;

    if(sh->sh_type != SHT_STRTAB)
      continue;
    if(strcmp(".strtab", shstrtab + sh->sh_name))
      continue;

    // We found the string table.
    strtab_sh = sh;
    break;
  }

  if(!strtab_sh)
  {
    fprintf(
      stderr,
      "Could not find string table for Elf file '%s'.\n", argv[1]
    );
    return 1;
  }

  // Load string table from ELF file.
  uint8_t strtab[strtab_sh->sh_size];
  fseek(elf, strtab_sh->sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
  fread(strtab, 1, sizeof(strtab), elf);

  // Now find symbol table
  for(size_t i = 0; i < eh.e_shnum; ++i)
  {
    Elf64_Shdr *sh = (void *) sht + i * eh.e_shentsize;

    // Skip this section entry if it is not a symbol table
    if(sh->sh_type != SHT_SYMTAB)
      continue;

    size_t sym_count = sh->sh_size / sh->sh_entsize;

    // Load the symbol table from the ELF file
    uint8_t symtab[sh->sh_size];
    fseek(elf, sh->sh_offset, SEEK_SET);
    fread(symtab, sh->sh_entsize, sym_count, elf);

    // Loop for each symbol and output a line in the linker
    // script for that symbol.
    for(size_t j = 1; j < sym_count; ++j)
    {
      Elf64_Sym *sym = (void *) symtab + j * sh->sh_entsize;
      char *name = strtab + sym->st_name;
      uint64_t val = sym->st_value;

      // If the name is empty skip this symbol.
      if(!strlen(name))
        continue;

      // If the symbol is not global, it should not
      // be outputed to the linker script.
      if(ELF64_ST_BIND(sym->st_info) != STB_GLOBAL)
        continue;

      fprintf(ld, "%s = %#0lx;\n", name, val);
    }
  }
}
```

The usage of the program is supposed to be as follows:

```bash
modldgen kernel.sym module.ld
```

An example of a line in `module.ld` is:

```
malloc = 0xffffffffffe02ede;
```

Then, the kernel modules would be linked in the following way:

```bash
x86_64-elf-gcc -T module.ld module_file1.o module_fileN.o -o module.mod -other-flags
```

The resulting file might be larger than what it needs to be because of all the unused symbols, so you might as well want to remove them with:

```bash
x86_64-elf-objcopy --strip-unneeded module.mod
```

The only thing that makes this not the best solution, is that when the kernel is rebuilt, functions might change their locations, and as a result, all modules need to be relinked as well.

## Solution II

The second solution, which was actually the first one I thought about, is to make the linking stage done by the kernel itself. That is, the C source files of a module will only be compiled, then the kernel will link them together and while doing so link any kernel symbols to their locations.

This solution while very ambitious, and in my opinion very clean, it is also very hard, a linker's job is very complicated, I couldn't fully understand relocations so I abandoned the idea in favor of the first solution.

This solves the only issue with the first solution, since the kernel is also the linker, all symbols will be replaced during runtime to whatever their value is.

If anybody wants to take this route, here is a very useful resource:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter6-46512.html#scrolltoc

## Solution III

Finally, there was a solution I only thought of but did not try implementing it, it is a dirtier version of the first solution.

The idea is to basically after compiling all module source files, chose one object file randomly and add kernel symbols to it, then when linking, the linker will think that object file defines those symbols within it.